# Standard C# templates not showing when adding new class to project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: installation, templates, visual-studio-2017

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2017 and am trying to add a new class with a standard template, however there are no C# templates in the “Add New Item” dialogue box that opens.  There are only VB templates showing under the Installed drop-down.  I have done a lot of searching online and tried:

- locating the templates in the installed folder (they seems to be in the right place - “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp”)
- uninstalling “Desktop Development with C++” feature and re-installing it (had no effect)
- repairing the installation of Visual Studio via the installer (had not effect)
- opening the Developer Command prompt as administrator and executing “devenv /installvstemplates” (had no effect, although from what I can see this might be for custom templates, not the standard installed ones..?)

As an aside, if I create a new project I can see the standard Visual C# templates along with the VB ones (and Visual C++ and Javascript).  I have also installed Visual Studio 2019 and have the same problem with that version.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix this?

Comment: I found an article stating that this was a bug that's since been fixed with VS 2017, but I'm having the same issues with VS 2019 too. 
 How do you add a class file otherwise? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2558/no-c-class-options-when-right-click-create-file-in.html

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a [bug with some versions of Visual Studio 2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2558/no-c-class-options-when-right-click-create-file-in.html) where the file templates don't load.

However, using Visual Studio 2019, I still had a similar problem, but was caused by my own mistake.  When creating a new project, in very small text the language is specified.

In my case, I clicked the `Visual Basic` example, which is higher in the list.  This creates a new ASP.NET Web Application, but ONLY with Visual Basic code support; preventing any `C#` examples from showing in the "New File -> New Class" dialog.

The fix was to create a new project using the correct new project template.

[image]

[image]